# Use of an object pronoun in a question

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots, questions

> Mange-t-il *le gâteau*?

Le **gâteau** has to be replaced using a direct complement pronoun (*le*) but where do I place it? The rule says behind the verb but here it can't be done.

Comment: "*the rule says behind the verb*" What rule?

Comment: On mange du gâteau ; remplace avec le partitif ou *le sandwich* ?  Sinon, "En mange-t-il  ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various alternatives:

> 1. Est-ce qu'il le mange ? (both formal and informal)
> 2. Il le mange ? (with rising intonation; rather informal)
> 3. Le mange-t-il ? (the most formal version)

In case of the passé composé (perfect in English), the respective phrases are as follow:

> 1. Est-ce qu'il l'a mangé ? (both formal and informal)
> 2. Il l'a mangé ? (that is, with rising intonation; rather informal)
> 3. L'a-t-il mangé ? (the most formal version)

Note that gateau is masculine. In the case of a feminine noun like la confiture we would write (phonetically there is no difference), respectively:

> 1. Est-ce qu'il l'a mangée ? (both formal and informal)
> 2. Il l'a mangée ? (with rising intonation; rather informal)
> 3. L'a-t-il mangée ? (the most formal version)

This is due to a phenomenon called "accord du participe passé".

Answer (score 0):

« **Le** mange-t-il » I think but not a sentence I would say IRL. (French native here)

Comment: Umm thanks. I thought the same too, but it seemed weird.

Comment: @RayyanAsifKhan It's because "*Mange-t-il le gâteau ?*" is weird to begin with (subject inversion is very uncommon in spoken language).